# В каком Режиме лучше всего использовать SASS/SCSS для большей эффективности?

Tags: css, css3, sass

Только-только начал изучать *SASS/SCSS* и возник следующий вопрос: какой режим выбрать? С командной строкой или лучше скачать программу?

Почему большинство *SASS/SCSS* разработчиков   предпочитают командную строку, нежели программу? Так более эффективно?

У меня *Windows*: для большей эффективности мне лучше использовать режим командной строки? А Программы (вроде коалы) содержат баги, потому большинство их не используют?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для начала изучения и для простых работ это не важно. Можно как угодно использовать. Главное тут сам язык, а переключиться потом не вопрос.

Разработчики используют командную строку, потому что так гибче, исключаются лишние этапы, больше возможностей. Да и просто привычнее и быстрее работать с текстом.

Кроме компиляции исходного файла в конечный файл, на проектах "не минимального размера" нужна ещё минификация, объединение в бандл и прочее. Для всего не найдёшь программ-окон, там нюансов куча, и много инструментов задействовано.

Также то, что предлагают эти программы, можно настроить в редакторе обычно. Например в вебшторме. Тоже будет компиляции при сохранении файла. Но, в отличие от тех программ, не будет задержки, которая часто бывает когда операционка не соизволит заметить сохранение файла.

Comment: Павел, спасибо большое